# In PostgreSQL, is it possible to query all the tables in a given database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, is it possible to query  all the tables in a given database for records that satisfy some condition?

```
Select [dbname "db"] *
From [all tables in database "db"]
Where [some condition on records]
```

The things inside [] are arbitrary up to what they are supposed to mean in general.

Comment: Perhaps in the [`information_schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html) which holds all of the metadata for your tables and columns. Could you explain more about what a *records' attributes' names* means and what `condition on records` you are looking for? `information_schema` will get you information about tables and columns and whatnot, but not about the data in them.

Comment: The things inside [] are arbitrary up to what they are supposed to mean in general.

Comment: Yes, you can list all the tables in the `FROM` clause.  There is not an automated way.

Comment: There's no direct way to do what I think you are asking. Please share some sample data from a few of these tables and what your desired results would be from this SQL that you are trying to put together. My guess is you will have to query against `information_schema` and then from those results, stitch together more SQL statements to issue to the database for each table you are interested in. It's impossible to say though with the information given. "Arbitrary" and "General"  as a *definition* of your term "Records' attributes' names" doesn't really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Could you be specific?

Comment: With your last update to use `*` what would your expected output be? If you only had two tables in the database but 1 had 10 columns and the other 20, how would they be returned in a single result set? Would you want two result sets in that situation?

Answer (score 2):

My best bet here is that you are wanting to return all rows from every table in a particular database that meet a certain condition. This gets tricky because:

1. It's necessary that the table upon which your condition is based be present in every table you are querying.
2. Furthermore, because your many tables in this one schema/database probably have different columns, you can't return them all in the same result set.
3. There is no "one" sql statement you can send to the database to do this. You will have to query at least twice. Once to get the list of tables, and once again to query those tables.

Consider a database/schema with two tables both with the column `F1`. We want all records from the tables in this schema where `F1=1`. So:

```
# CREATE TABLE public.t2 (f1 int, f2 varchar(20), f3 date);
    CREATE TABLE
# CREATE TABLE public.t1 (f1 int, f4 varchar(40), f5 varchar(10), f6 int);
    CREATE TABLE
# SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public';
     table_catalog | table_schema | table_name | table_type | self_referencing_column_name | reference_generation | user_defined_type_catalog | user_defined_type_schema | user_defined_type_name | is_insertable_into | is_typed | commit_action 
    ---------------+--------------+------------+------------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+----------+---------------
     username      | public       | t2         | BASE TABLE |                              |                      |                           |                          |                        | YES                | NO       | 
     username      | public       | t1         | BASE TABLE |                              |                      |                           |                          |                        | YES                | NO       | 
    (2 rows)

# SELECT 'SELECT * FROM public.' || table_name || ' WHERE f1=1;' FROM 
    information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public';
                  ?column?               
    -------------------------------------
     SELECT * FROM public.t2 WHERE f1=1;
     SELECT * FROM public.t1 WHERE f1=1;
    (2 rows)
```

That last SQL generates two records (one for each table in the schema) querying it for records where your condition is true. You can now execute each of these separately to get your results (in two result sets).

```
# SELECT * FROM public.t2 WHERE f1=1;SELECT * FROM public.t1 WHERE f1=1;
     f1 | f2 | f3 
    ----+----+----
    (0 rows)

     f1 | f4 | f5 | f6 
    ----+----+----+----
    (0 rows)
```

---

If every table in your schema is exactly the same (same number of columns, order of columns, and data types) then you could query `information_Schema` and build a UNION query to then execute separately:

```
# CREATE TABLE public.t1 (f1 int, f2 varchar(20), f3 date);
    CREATE TABLE
# CREATE TABLE public.t2 (f1 int, f2 varchar(20), f3 date);
    CREATE TABLE
# INSERT INTO public.t1 VALUES (1, 'test', '2019-04-22'),(2, 'test2', '2019-04-22');
    INSERT 0 2
# INSERT INTO public.t2 VALUES (1, 'testtest', '2019-04-21'),(2, 'testest2', '2019-04-20');
    INSERT 0 2
# SELECT 'SELECT * FROM public.' || table_name || ' WHERE f1=1' || CASE WHEN LEAD(table_name) OVER (ORDER BY table_name) IS NOT NULL THEN ' UNION ALL' ELSE ';' END FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public';
                       ?column?                   
    ----------------------------------------------
     SELECT * FROM public.t1 WHERE f1=1 UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM public.t2 WHERE f1=1;
    (2 rows)
# SELECT * FROM public.t1 WHERE f1=1 UNION ALL
-#  SELECT * FROM public.t2 WHERE f1=1;
     f1 |    f2    |     f3     
    ----+----------+------------
      1 | test     | 2019-04-22
      1 | testtest | 2019-04-21
    (2 rows)
```

You can see that neither option is pretty since you have to dynamically write SQL and then separately execute it.

Comment: Although if "every table in your schema is exactly the same (same number of columns, order of columns, and data types)", I'd say the OP has bigger problems...

Comment: @Zack You and I both, but I wanted to share that option since I feel like it's a bit more in-line with what OP was asking for even though the potential for getting to use it is virtually non-existent (or worrying in a *"I have a `user` database and in it a table for every new user"* type of way).